# Evaluating an expectation of the supremum of collection of random variables

Tags: integration, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

I know that $\mathbb{E}(sup_n|X_n|)=\infty$ if $X_n=\frac{2^n}n\cdot\mathbf 1_{(1/2^{n+1},1/2^n)}$. However I am not sure how this can be evaluated explicitly. The probability space is $Ω=[0,1]$ endowed with its Borel sigma-algrebra and Lebesgue measure.

I get that

$\begin{align} \displaystyle \mathbb{E}(sup_n|X_n|) &=\int sup_n |X_n| d\mathbb{P} \\ 
&=\int sup_n \Big( \frac{2^n}{n}\cdot\mathbf 1_{(1/2^{n+1},1/2^n)}\Big) d\mu \\
\end{align}$

but not sure how this would evaluated.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847204/find-a-sequence-of-r-vs-satisfying-the-following-conditions if you feel you need more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{(1/2^{k+1},1/2^k)}=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]},\quad\lambda\, \text{- a.s.}
$$
since they agree except in countably many points. Since $X_n$ is non-negative, $|X_n|=X_n$, and
$$
\int_{[0,1]}\sup_n |X_n|\,\mathrm d\lambda=\int_{[0,1]} \sup_n X_n\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}\,\mathrm d\lambda=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{[0,1]}\sup_n X_n\mathbf{1}_{(1/2^{k+1},1/2^k)}\,\mathrm d\lambda.
$$
But $\sup\limits_n X_n=\frac{2^k}{k}$ on the set $(1/2^{k+1},1/2^k)$ and hence
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]}\sup_n |X_n|\,\mathrm d\lambda&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{[0,1]} \frac{2^k}{k}\mathbf{1}_{(1/2^{k+1},1/2^k)}\,\mathrm d\lambda\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right)=\infty.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: what gives you the right to do $\int_0^1\sup_n |X_n|\,\mathrm d\lambda=\int_\mathbb{R} \sup_n X_n\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}\,\mathrm d\lambda$

Comment: I dont see why we are using this $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{(1/2^{k+1},1/2^k)}=\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)},\quad\lambda\, \text{- a.s.}$

Comment: Nevermind the first, there is no need to introduce $\mathbb{R}$ here. I am using that equality in the second equality of the second equation.